# Symfony2.8 with sonataEcommerce2.1.1 single Product page "requires that you provide a value for the "$product" argument"

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-2.8, sonata-user-bundle

I am using sonata-ecommerce. When I try to open single product page then Controller error occure.
Here is detailed error. 
"Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Controller\ProductController::viewAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$product" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

[image]

Comment: After try this solution:- Then extend this class from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` not `BaseProductController`. Then blank Single product page appears. Please help me if any one know sonata. First time using symfony and sonata bundles.

Comment: This problem is solved:-

Comment: Ans:- No need to change the extend.
Here is my Code:-
Copy viewAction from vendor/sonata-project/ecommerce/ProductBundle/controller/Basecontroller and place it in src/Application/Sonata/COntroller/ProductController. 
    After copy assign $product = null in the ApplicationSonataProductBundle..
    public function viewAction($product = null)
    {
        //Add these lines.
        $slug = $this->getRequest()->get('slug');
        $productId = $this->getRequest()->get('productId');
        $product = $this->get('sonata.product.set.manager')->findEnabledFromIdAndSlug($productId, $slug);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to change the extend. 
Here is my Code:- 
Copy viewAction from vendor/sonata-project/ecommerce/ProductBundle/controller/Basecontroller and place it in src/Application/Sonata/Controller/ProductController. 
After copy assign $product = null in the ApplicationSonataProductBundle.

```
public function viewAction($product = null) { 
    //Add these lines. 
    $slug = $this->getRequest()->get('slug'); 
    $productId = $this->getRequest()->get('productId'); 
    $product = $this->get('sonata.product.set.manager')->findEnabledFromIdAndSlug($productId, $slug);
....
}
```